# jQuery scrollTo works only after Chrome 61

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, google-chrome, angular-material

I'm working on an Angular 2/4 project and I have to scroll up in case of every navigation change ... which is complicated due to I use sidenav (Angular Material) and a lot of other things.
I just experienced a really annoying problem, which is the following:

```ts
this.router
    .events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .subscribe(() => {
         const contentContainer = document.querySelector('.mat-drawer-content');
         contentContainer.scrollTo(0, 0);
     });
```

It scrolls up in case of any navigation between child components, and even if I navigate somewhere else (to sibling routes).
It works properly in Firefox, and newer versions of Chrome ( >=61 ), but unfortunately throws the following exception if I use e.g. Chrome 60 or 59 (not tested for any other versions yet).

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: e.scrollTo is not a function

I use prebuilt jQuery 2.1.1, and as I've searched for the issue it seems that there was a breaking change in Chrome v61. But my problem is just the opposite: it works higher versions and not on lower ones ...

Is it possible to make it work on every (relevant) Chrome version?

Comment: Thats not a jQuery thing, its vanilla JS. I think its actually just something you can trigger on `window`?

Comment: maybe you are right.. I have a few calls with window.scrollTo(0, 0);.. why do you think this is the problem instead of what I've mentioned? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually **[`scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)** is not a jQuery function, it's defined in JavaScript and you can't call `scrollTo()` on an element, it's a method defined only in `window` object, that's why you got `e.scrollTo is not a function`.

You can only call it on `window` like this:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

If you check the [**window.scrollTo()** Notes on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo#Notes) you will see that:

> For scrolling elements, see [`Element.scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) and [`Element.scrollLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft).

Comment: thanks, I will test it tomorrow with other versions of Chrome!

Comment: Thank you! it works fine even with lower versions of Chrome!!